# Time taken to walk both ways

Tags: linear-algebra

A man walks a certain distance and rides back in $\frac{15}4$ hours; he could ride both ways in $\frac52$ hours. How much time will he take to walk both ways. 
I know the answer but please tell me where I am wrong.
$x =$ time taken to ride once, $y =$ time taken to walk once.
$\frac1x + \frac1y = \frac4{15}$ and $\frac1x + \frac1x = \frac25$, so $x = 5$, but $x$ is not $5$.

Comment: Why take reciprocals?

Comment: @user121049 If x is the time to ride once, then 1/x = 1/time taken to ride, the formula we use for time and work.

Comment: if speed is constant, I do not see a problem with your solution: $\frac{5}{2}+\frac{5}{4}=\frac{15}{4}$

Comment: We know it takes him $\frac 54$ of an hour to ride one way.  Thus it takes him $\frac {10}4$ of an hour to walk one way.  Therefore it takes $2\times \frac {10}4=\frac {20}4=5$ hours to walk both ways.

Comment: @TStancek If x is 5 then time taken to ride both ways = 10 hours.

Comment: @lulu Sorry but hwo do you know time taken to walk is twice the time to ride?

Comment: Well, I don't know that in one step (though it is obviously true).  But you said that "walking one way and riding the other" took $\frac {15}4$ and since riding one way takes $\frac 54$ we can just subtract....$\frac {15}4-\frac 54=\frac {10}4$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $d$ units is the one-way distance, $x$ units/hour is the speed of the man while walking and $y$ units/hour is the speed while riding.

Hence we have 
\begin{align}
\dfrac{d}{x} + \dfrac{d}{y} = \dfrac{15}{4} \text{ hours} \tag{1}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
& \dfrac{d}{y} + \dfrac{d}{y} = \dfrac{5}{2} \text{ hours} \\
\implies & \dfrac{d}{y} = \dfrac{5}{4} \text{ hours} \tag{2} 
\end{align}
Using (1) and (2), we have 
\begin{align}
\dfrac{d}{x} = \dfrac{10}{4}\text{ hours}
\end{align}
Hence, total time required if the man walks both the ways is
\begin{align}
\dfrac{2d}{x} = \dfrac{20}{4} = 5 \text{ hours}
\end{align}

Comment: Right sir, but where is my approach going wrong? Or is my method wrong?

Comment: @RamKeswani: As per your notations - $x$ is the time taken to ride once and $y$ is the time taken to walk once. Then as per the statement of the problem, $x + y = \dfrac{15}{4} \implies \dfrac{1}{x+y} = \dfrac{4}{15} \neq \dfrac{1}{x} + \dfrac{1}{y}$ (as you proceed)